# Automated command to generate composer.json?

Tags: composer-php

Is there an automated command to generate the composer.json file? I was hoping for something interactive that just asks me the package names and dumps them into a composer.json file interactively. I somehow remember using something like this in the past... I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`composer init`, see [docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#init) for more.

Comment: You have golden eye :)